# jQuery Selector: show onclick

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-selectors

I'm having a bit of trouble getting a certain div to show onclick. Any takers?

**HTML**

```
<div style="float:left;width:40px;">
<span class="productControl" style="position:relative;">
    <div class="productMenuHolder" style="display:none;">
    <ul class="productMenuList">
        <li class="productMenuItem">Add to Collection</li>
        <li class="productMenuItem">Share</li>
    </ul>
    </div>
</span>
</div>
```

**jQuery**

```
$("span.productControl").click(function(){
    $(this).next().show();
});
```

The productMenuHolder doesn't seem to show up!

Comment: Are you using `$(function () { ... });` to make sure your handlers are being bound?  Also, why does your span contain your div?  That'll cause problems later.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$(this).find('.productMenuHolder').show()
```

I suggest you look a bit closer at the markup.

Comment: Thank you @meder. Why does .next not work? (I will accept your answer, but stack will let me do it in 9 min)

Comment: next means next sibling, not child. span owns div.

Comment: Ahh...stupid stupid stupid ::hitting head with hands::

As a follow up, how would I make the popup div hide when someone clicks anywhere but the productMenuHolder div?